# SQL query - db2/400 iseries

Tags: sql, case, ibm-midrange, db2-400, subquery

My SQL group statement results in the below table. From this table, I need to subtract Qty with Code ='S' from Qty with code ='B' when Price and Date are matching.

For example, in the below table I need the value to be stored in a work variable.

1) 100-50  = 50 for the first 2 rows
 2) 60 -30  = 30 for the 3rd and 4 th row
 3) The last row since it does not have code 'S' it should return just 20

Table

```
Price    Date        Code    Sum(Qty)
9.0      201512       B       100
9.0      201512       S       50
8.0      201506       B       60
6.0      201506       S       30
5.0      201508       B       20
```

SQL query used to get the above table

```
select Price, Date, Code,sum(Qty) from Table
   where    Type = 'A' and  Acct = 'CLOSED'
   group by  Price,Date,Code
   order by Price,Date
```

Can I modify my existing SQL statement typed above using CASE statements to get my required output. I tried it but Cursor returns one by one row and CASE does not seem to work

```
exec sql
declare c1 cursor for
select Price, Date, Code,
Case when Code ='B' then  ifnull(sum(Qty),0)
    when Code ='S' then  (-1 * ifnull(sum(Qty),0)) end
from Table

where    Type = 'A' and  Acct = 'CLOSED'
group by  Price,Date,Code
order by Price,Date

exec sql
open c1

exec sql
fetch c1  into :var_price, :var_date, :var_code, :var_Bqty, :VarSqty
```

Using SQLRPGLE on iseries system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select Price, Date,
       sum(case when code = 'B' then Qty when code = 'S' then -QTY end) as diff
from Table
where Type = 'A' and Acct = 'CLOSED'
group by Price, Date
order by Price, Date;
```